# Labels are blank in Decision Tree plot in r

Tags: r, decision-tree, r-caret

I am using caret package to train my model.

My model is working fine. But when I plot the decision tree, the labels are blank. How do i get the labels?

```
carMod <- train( FLAG ~.,data=df_train, method="rpart" )
plot(carMod$finalModel)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need

```
plot(carMod$finalModel)
text(carMod$finalModel)
```

Comment: Thanks. It partially worked. But the root node label is missing and for information is incomplete for leaf nodes.

Comment: You didn't specify anything precise what you want to see. See `?text.rpart` for possible options. E.g., `use.n = TRUE` adds more information. As for the root, try something like `margin = -2` in the `plot` call. Keep in mind that you also provided neither an expected output nor your data. See also rpart.plot, partykit, and maptree packages.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, as explained on the help page for `plot.rpart` (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/rpart/html/plot.rpart.html):

```
plot(carMod$finalModel)
text(carMod$finalModel)
```

Alternatively use

```
library(rpart.plot)
rpart.plot(carMod$finalModel)
```

For more information, see https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/06/plotting-classification-and-regression-trees-with-plotrpart.html